# How to use synonym stored procedures in ssrs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, reporting-services, synonym

I want to make a SSRS report using a stored procedure from another sql database.
I made a synonym via SQL Server:

```
Use DataBase1;

CREATE SYNONYM StoredProcedure1 FOR DataBase2.dbo.StoredProcedure1;

go
```

In SSRS Design I could not find "StoredProcedure1" in DataBase1. How I can access it?

Comment: Using SSMS, can you see your synonym in Database1.Synonyms?

Comment: I can see it in synonyms. But I can not use it in SSRS. I made multiple views in Database1 from tables in Database2. Then, I made the same stored procedure  in Database1. That way I could make my report in SSRS. But, I didn't use synonym.

Answer (score 0):

My fellow colleague in the same team got stuck at the same situation and no solution seems working. So my solution was the, create sp in the database which directly used by SSRS and call the synonym inside that sp. Worked there correctly. But need to know proper solution.

The given case create new SP like here.

```
USE [DataBase1] 

CREATE PROCEDURE New_SP
    
AS
BEGIN
    
    EXEC StoredProcedure1 

END
GO
```

Then use the newly created sp in SSRS.